# Subroutine unexpectedly ends when a Workbook is closed

Tags: vba, excel, subroutine, userform

my problem today is a part of a subroutine that inexplicably breaks its execution when a `Workbook` is closed.
I have written the following code:

```
Public Const Pi As Double = 3.14159265358979
Public Const Rad As Double = Pi / 180 
Public CalcBook As Workbook
Public FilePath As String, Files() As String
Public FreqArray() As Integer

Sub Main()

Dim ChooseFolder As Object, FilePath As String, StrFile As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, x As Integer
Dim DirNum As Integer, HNum As Integer, VNum As Integer
Dim DirColShift As Integer, HColShift As Integer, VColShift As Integer
Dim TheStart As Date, TheEnd As Date, TotalTime As Date

Set ChooseFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With ChooseFolder
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please choose a folder containing .txt files"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        FilePath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    Else
        Set ChooseFolder = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
Set ChooseFolder = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

' Stores only files containing an AntennaName + "_T" + any number of characters + "_?_?45.xls" string
' (where "?" is a single character and "*" is any number). Checks if the number of files is correct too.

StrFile = Dir(FilePath & "*_T*_?_?45.txt")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    ReDim Preserve Files(i)
    Files(i) = FilePath & StrFile
    i = i + 1
    StrFile = Dir
Loop


If Not (UBound(Files) + 1) / 6 = Int((UBound(Files) + 1) / 6) Then GoTo FileError
For i = 0 To UBound(Files)
    Select Case Right(Files(i), 9)
    Case "D_+45.txt", "D_-45.txt"
        DirNum = DirNum + 1
    Case "H_+45.txt", "H_-45.txt"
        HNum = HNum + 1
    Case "V_+45.txt", "V_-45.txt"
        VNum = VNum + 1
    End Select
Next
If Not (DirNum / 2 = Int(DirNum / 2) And HNum / 2 = Int(HNum / 2) And VNum / 2 = Int(VNum / 2) And DirNum = HNum And HNum = VNum) Then
FileError:
    MsgBox "Failed to properly load files. Looks like a wrong number of them is at dispose", vbCritical, "Check the import-files"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Imports files in Excel for better data access

Set CalcBook = Application.Workbooks.Add

' FROM HERE ON THE DATA IS PROCESSED IN ORDER TO OBTAIN AN EXCEL WORKBOOK WITH 3 SHEETS CALLED "Directivity", "Horizontal" and "Vertical".

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Options.Show

TheStart = Now

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Options.OnlyEval = False Then PolarCharts
If Options.OnlyCharts = False Then Auswertung
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
CalcBook.Close savechanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Set CalcBook = Nothing

TheEnd = Now
TotalTime = TheEnd - TheStart
MsgBox Format(TotalTime, "HH:MM:SS"), vbInformation, "Computing Time"

Unload Options

End Sub
```

`Options` is a form which I need in order to access data for the `PolarCharts` and `Auswertung`. These Subs are correctly executed (I know that because the data they save is correct too).

I tried deleting the `.ScreenUpdating` and `.DisplayAlerts` commands, as well as the `Unload` thinking that they could bugging something, but the result hasn't changed.

Know also that the Workbook I'm closing contains NO CODE at all (and nothing else addresses a ".Close" so it's impossible that something is executed on the .Close event).

Below my "Options" code:

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    End
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    End
End Sub

Private Sub Ok_Click()

    If Me.OnlyCharts = False Then

        ReDim SubFreq(4)

        If Not (Me.Start1.ListIndex = -1 And Me.Stop1.ListIndex = -1) Then SubFreq(0) = Me.Start1.List(Me.Start1.ListIndex) & "-" & Me.Stop1.List(Me.Stop1.ListIndex)
        If Not (Me.Start2.ListIndex = -1 And Me.Stop2.ListIndex = -1) Then SubFreq(1) = Me.Start2.List(Me.Start2.ListIndex) & "-" & Me.Stop2.List(Me.Stop2.ListIndex)
        If Not (Me.Start3.ListIndex = -1 And Me.Stop3.ListIndex = -1) Then SubFreq(2) = Me.Start3.List(Me.Start3.ListIndex) & "-" & Me.Stop3.List(Me.Stop3.ListIndex)
        If Not (Me.Start4.ListIndex = -1 And Me.Stop4.ListIndex = -1) Then SubFreq(3) = Me.Start4.List(Me.Start4.ListIndex) & "-" & Me.Stop4.List(Me.Stop4.ListIndex)
        If Not (Me.Start5.ListIndex = -1 And Me.Stop5.ListIndex = -1) Then SubFreq(4) = Me.Start5.List(Me.Start5.ListIndex) & "-" & Me.Stop5.List(Me.Stop5.ListIndex)

        If (Me.Start1 = "" And Me.Start2 = "" And Me.Start3 = "" And Me.Start4 = "" And Me.Start5 = "" And Me.Stop1 = "" And Me.Stop2 = "" And Me.Stop3 = "" And Me.Stop4 = "" And Me.Stop5 = "") _
        Or Me.Start1.Value > Me.Stop1.Value Or Me.Start2.Value > Me.Stop2.Value Or Me.Start3.Value > Me.Stop3.Value Or Me.Start4.Value > Me.Stop4.Value Or Me.Start5.Value > Me.Stop5.Value _
        Or (Me.Start1.ListIndex = -1 And Me.Stop1.ListIndex >= 0) Or (Me.Start2.ListIndex = -1 And Me.Stop2.ListIndex >= 0) Or (Me.Start3.ListIndex = -1 And Me.Stop3.ListIndex >= 0) Or (Me.Start4.ListIndex = -1 And Me.Stop4.ListIndex >= 0) Or (Me.Start5.ListIndex = -1 And Me.Stop5.ListIndex >= 0) _
        Or (Me.Start1.ListIndex >= 0 And Me.Stop1.ListIndex = -1) Or (Me.Start2.ListIndex >= 0 And Me.Stop2.ListIndex = -1) Or (Me.Start3.ListIndex >= 0 And Me.Stop3.ListIndex = -1) Or (Me.Start4.ListIndex >= 0 And Me.Stop4.ListIndex = -1) Or (Me.Start5.ListIndex >= 0 And Me.Stop5.ListIndex = -1) Then
            MsgBox("Please select correctly the frequency ranges - Maybe Start > Stop, one of those was not properly inserted, or the fields are blank", vbExclamation, "Frequency choice error")
            GoTo hell
        End If

        For i = 0 To 4
            If Not SubFreq(i) = "" Then j = j + 1
        Next i
        j = j - 1
        ReDim Preserve SubFreq(j)

    End If

    Me.Hide

hell:
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim i As Byte

    Me.StartMeas = Date
    Me.StopMeas = Date

    Me.Worker.AddItem "lol"
    Me.Worker.AddItem "rofl"
    Me.Worker.ListIndex = 0

    For i = LBound(FreqArray) To UBound(FreqArray)
        Me.Start1.AddItem FreqArray(i)
        Me.Start2.AddItem FreqArray(i)
        Me.Start3.AddItem FreqArray(i)
        Me.Start4.AddItem FreqArray(i)
        Me.Start5.AddItem FreqArray(i)
        Me.Stop1.AddItem FreqArray(i)
        Me.Stop2.AddItem FreqArray(i)
        Me.Stop3.AddItem FreqArray(i)
        Me.Stop4.AddItem FreqArray(i)
        Me.Stop5.AddItem FreqArray(i)
    Next i

    Me.Start1.ListIndex = 0
    Me.Stop1.ListIndex = Me.Stop1.ListCount - 1

End Sub
```

Apparently when I `Close` CalcBook, it triggers the `UserForm_Terminate` event from Options which `End`s all the code! How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **remove** the statement `End` bacause `End` causes the abrupt end of code execution.

I see `End` in the `Cancel` and `Terminate` event handlers. *If you have it on other places, remove it es well*.

If you need exit from a method then use `Exit Sub`.

Why: because `End` work that way. Read e.g. this post: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?511766-Classic-VB-Why-is-using-the-End-statement-(or-VB-s-quot-stop-quot-button)-a-bad-idea.

If you need stop code from execution use `If-condition` or even `Exit Sub` but avoid using `End` for it.

Comment: The only thing is: I can't stop "Main" from executing should "Options" handle a Cancel_Click or a UserForm_Terminate. The problem itself is in the UserForm_Terminate, since when I close without saving the Workbook a "UserForm_Terminate" is invoked (I have no clue why). 
I DO need all the code to end should the X on the userform be clicked

Comment: In the code you posted I do not see any 'stop' in 'Main'? And in the handlers 'Click' und 'Terminate' there is no code exept 'End' or? 'Terminate' should be called when you call 'Unload Options'. I do not see any relation between the 'CalcBook' and the 'Options' form, or is there any. So I am confused as well.

Comment: Somehow the code never reaches the `Unload Options` and the funny part is that in `CalcBook` there is absolutely no code! So an on event unload trigger can't be the mistake

Comment: @Noldor130884, Add a public variable to `Options` called `Result`. If `Options` is cancelled let `Result = False` else set it to `True`. Check the value of `Result` in `Main` to find out if it was cancelled. Then you don't need `End`.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
Workbooks("CalcBook").Close savechanges:=False
```

I suspect that both error alerts and indications of an error on the screen are being suppressed

Comment: Can't work: There is no Workbook with a "CalcBook" name. I previously set Calcbook to be a specific new Workbook.