# Why does Workbook.Close trigger the UserForm_Terminate? - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, crash

There is some problem in the following code, which is driving me mad. I can't seem to find the reason why the code suddendly ends when an Excel `Workbook` gets automatically closed.

The code is executed from an Excel Workbook and works like this:

- It opens another Workbook (WbLOP)
- Creates a third Workbook (TargetWb)
- Copies some data from WbLOP to TargetWb
- Closes WbLOP

Whole code below:

```
Public WbLOP As Workbook, WsLop As Worksheet
Public AbtToEval As String

Sub Std_Ausw()

Dim OpenDialog As Object, FileName As String
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Termin As Date
Dim TargetWb As Workbook, TargetWs As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, w As Integer
Dim ZielCol As Integer, ZielNEWCol As Integer, PEPStatusCol As Integer, StatusAICol As Integer
Dim ActivityRow As Integer

' Asks user input file to read from
Set OpenDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With OpenDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm"
    If .Show Then
        FileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Set OpenDialog = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
Set OpenDialog = Nothing

' Checks if the worksheet "LOP" is contained in the file
Set WbLOP = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
For Each Ws In WbLOP.Worksheets
    If UCase(Ws.Name) = "LOP" Then
        Set WsLop = Ws
        Exit For
    End If
Next
On Error Resume Next
If WsLop.Name = "" Then
    WbLOP.Close savechanges:=False
    Set WbLOP = Nothing
    MsgBox "Fail"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' Shows a Userform to let user decide the name of the AbtToEval
Ausw.Show
```

I'm pasting here the code of the UserForm:

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    End
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    End
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Abt() As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

' Searches for the PD-Abt column
i = 1
Do Until LCase(WsLop.Cells(8, i)) = "pd-abt"
    i = i + 1
Loop

' Copies the unique Abt in an array
j = 10
ReDim Abt(0)
Abt(0) = UCase(WsLop.Cells(j, i))
Do Until IsEmpty(WsLop.Cells(j, 1))
    For k = 0 To UBound(Abt)
        If Abt(k) = UCase(WsLop.Cells(j, i)) Then
            Exit For
        Else
            If k = UBound(Abt) Then
                ReDim Preserve Abt(UBound(Abt) + 1)
                Abt(UBound(Abt)) = UCase(WsLop.Cells(j, i))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    j = j + 1
Loop

' Initializes the combo-box with the Abt names
For i = 0 To UBound(Abt)
    Me.AbtBox.AddItem Abt(i)
Next
Me.AbtBox.ListIndex = 0

End Sub

Private Sub OK_Click()
    AbtToEval = Me.AbtBox.List(Me.AbtBox.ListIndex)
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

And here the main Sub is resumed

```
' Opens a new workbook and copies the table from the template
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set TargetWb = Application.Workbooks.Add
Do Until TargetWb.Sheets.Count = 1
    TargetWb.Sheets(TargetWb.Sheets.Count).Delete
Loop
Set TargetWs = TargetWb.Sheets(1)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A1:J3").Copy Destination:=TargetWs.Range("A1")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
TargetWs.Range("A2") = AbtToEval

' Sets a standard limit of 4 weeks from today
Termin = DateAdd("ww", 4, Date)

' Searches for the Ziel-Datum columns
i = 1
Do Until InStr(1, LCase(WsLop.Cells(8, i)), "ziel-datum") <> 0
    i = i + 1
Loop
If InStr(1, LCase(WsLop.Cells(8, i)), "neu") <> 0 Then
    ZielNEWCol = i
    i = i + 1
    Do Until InStr(1, LCase(WsLop.Cells(8, i)), "ziel-datum") <> 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    ZielCol = i
Else
    ZielCol = i
    i = i + 1
    Do Until InStr(1, LCase(WsLop.Cells(8, i)), "ziel-datum") <> 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    ZielNEWCol = i
End If

' Searches for the status columns
i = 1
Do Until InStr(1, LCase(WsLop.Cells(8, i)), "pep status") <> 0
    i = i + 1
Loop
PEPStatusCol = i
i = 1
Do Until InStr(1, LCase(WsLop.Cells(8, i)), "status ai") <> 0
    i = i + 1
Loop
StatusAICol = i

' Searches for the activities to do
i = 0
j = 0
Do Until IsEmpty(WsLop.Cells(9 + i, 1))
    If Not WsLop.Cells(9 + i, PEPStatusCol) = "akt" Then GoTo Go_Forth
    If WsLop.Cells(9 + i, StatusAICol) = "ges" Then GoTo Go_Forth
    If IsEmpty(WsLop.Cells(9 + i, ZielNEWCol)) Then
        If CDate(WsLop.Cells(9 + i, ZielCol)) > Termin Then
            GoTo Go_Forth
        Else
            ActivityRow = 9 + i
        End If
    Else
        If CDate(WsLop.Cells(9 + i, ZielNEWCol)) > Termin Then
            GoTo Go_Forth
        Else
            ActivityRow = 9 + i
        End If
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A4:J4").Copy Destination:=TargetWs.Cells(4 + j, 1)
    For w = 1 To 10
        k = 1
        Do Until TargetWs.Cells(3, w) = WsLop.Cells(8, k)
            k = k + 1
        Loop
        TargetWs.Cells(4 + j, w) = WsLop.Cells(ActivityRow, k)
    Next
    j = j + 1
Go_Forth:
    i = i + 1
Loop

' If TargetSheet is empty then shows only a message
If IsEmpty(TargetWs.Cells(4, 1)) Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TargetWb.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "We have no bananas before " & Format(Termin, "dd.mm.yyyy") & " for the " & AbtToEval & "!", vbInformation, AbtToEval & " out of bananas"
Else
    ' If the activity is in the past, it is marked in red
    i = 4
    Do Until IsEmpty(TargetWs.Cells(i, 1))
        If IsEmpty(TargetWs.Cells(i, 2)) Then
            If CDate(TargetWs.Cells(i, 1)) <= Date Then TargetWs.Range(Cells(i, 1).Address(0, 0), Cells(i, 10).Address(0, 0)).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
            If CDate(TargetWs.Cells(i, 2)) <= Date Then TargetWs.Range(Cells(i, 1).Address(0, 0), Cells(i, 10).Address(0, 0)).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    ' Fixes the visual and adds filters
    TargetWs.Range("A4").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    TargetWs.Range("A3:J3").AutoFilter
    TargetWs.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End If

' Ending
Set TargetWs = Nothing
Set TargetWb = Nothing
Set WsLop = Nothing
WbLOP.Close savechanges:=False
Set WbLOP = Nothing

End Sub
```

I managed to find a workaround playing with `if WbLOP Is Nothing Then End` in the `UserForm_Terminate` event, which as pointed out in some comments/answers is being triggered by the `Workbook.Close` event, but apparently if I execute the code where `TargetWb` is closed instead, nothing happens.
The event is basically linked to the `WbLOP.Close` and I still don't get why.

Comment: if your code is not too long, can you post the rest of it ?

Comment: Does it change the behaviour if you remove the two `End` statements from your userform code?

Comment: YES! I removed the `Private Sub UserForm Terminate` in the UserForm code and apparently now everything works smoothly! BUT, if I now click on the "x" above the UserForm to close it, the code below is executed. I want it instead to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't posted full code - run your code in debug mode. Add breakpoints at points where you want to look closely what is happening. Use F5 to run (it will stop on next breakpoint or run till end) and F8 for step mode (move to next line). Use watch table to check values of your variables or whole IF contiodions to determine when the code should branch or do something specific.

Debug mode:

[image: Code debug]

### EDIT

Is there any chance it might be something like the problem you had in the past [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759635/subroutine-unexpectedly-ends-when-a-workbook-is-closed)?

[image]

### EDIT 2

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278823.aspx):

[image: MSDN]

Terminate event is triggered when object is unloaded. First workbook close works OK as the form hasn't been loaded. If the form is an object of that workbook when workbook close is performed it unloads the form and triggers UserForm_Terminate resulting in END - code stops execution.

Apparently this will be executed on every closure of form (even hiding it)

```
Private Sub userform_terminate()
'Code 
End Sub
```

You should be using this to detect when user closed it by the x button:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then ' =0 or = vbFormControlMenu 
         'Code 
    End If
End Sub
```

Then it will be only executed when user closed the form, but not when form has been unloaded, so replace your `userform_terminate` with the above alternative and it should work fine.

Comment: I'm not new to debugging a code, and the only problem I'm having is at the end of the code, where the sub is **ended** without any message. Besides, I did eventually post my code

Comment: @Noldor130884 Ican't tell if you are new or not, as your sub ends without message I guess it has to reach exit sub or similar function, are you absolutely certain that it doesn't get to exit sub in:

`    WbLOP.Close savechanges:=False
    Set WbLOP = Nothing
    MsgBox "Fail"
    Exit Sub`

As for the code you updated the question in the time while I was already typing the answer. Take it easy, if the answer doesn't help ignore it - it's that simple.

Comment: I am absolutely sure about it, since if, during the first bit of code, the sub ended in a strange fashion, it would have never shown the `MsgBox`

Comment: Is there any chance it is the UserForm_Terminate event stopping the code that you encountered once? See edit in the answer above.

Comment: At this point I think that the events are related. But why should a `Workbook.Close` trigger the `UserForm_Terminate` ?

Comment: Even stranger: I managed to find a workaround playing with `if WbLOP Is Nothing Then End`, but apparently if execute the code where `TargetWb` is closed, nothing happens. The event is basically linked to `WbLOP`

Comment: It absolutely shouldn't on its own, unless it was told to do it. It seems that you might need to resolve it using methods suggested in that other question. As suggested there you should try and to the clean close instead of using END, maybe that has something to do with it.
If you will be able please share the whole xlsm file, it will be interesting to see how it works and why.

Comment: I can't use `Exit Sub` because on the termination of the userform, it is not what I want to do. I want to End everything and that's it, so an `End` is rather efficient in my case. As I'm saying in my edit to the question, nothing seems to explain why *that particular* Workbook is somehow linked to the `UserForm Terminate` event. I'm sorry but I can't share the file, due to sensitive informations contained in it... It would take some time to make a copy and remove everything...

Comment: I thought that will be the case.

You might need to alter the code in a way to unload the form when it is terminated and return a value to your main sub. 
Then when the form is closed and your sub is resumed it will need to check returned value to determine whether it shall resume or abort and then you can do clean close.

As UserForm_Terminate occurs only once in the code - what initiates that sub, where is it called?

Comment: There are a number of workarounds I can think of, but I really need to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: The reason is that END is called, if you call END it will kill everything, along with the main sub. I cannot see any direct call of the UserForm_Terminate and it has to be triggered somehow, otherwise you can delete it from the code - what is your trigger for it at the moment? As you want your code to continue you don't really want the END as this is equivalent as going through your code in debug step mode and hitting a stop button - you would not expect your main sub to resume when you do it.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my need for the `End`: The form appears, I want to click on the "x" above to close it and terminate *everything* -> `End` is perfect. I do understand how it works, but there is absolutely **no calling** the `UserForm_Terminate` event when I close the workbook. I need to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought you still want to resume and do some alternative code execution. So the `END` does make sense. Looking at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278823.aspx - `Private Sub  object _Terminate( )` event is initiated when object is unloaded. Mystery solved, form "Ausw" is an object of WbLOP. When you close the workbook it unloads the form and triggers UserForm_Terminate. That is why your first close works fine because form hasn't been loaded yet so no _Terminate event is triggered.

Comment: @Noldor130884 I have updated the answer, try the option suggested at the end and see if that works.

Comment: That is a great workaround and works flawlessly up to a point... But no, the UserForm is nothing that I called from the Workbook I opened, so this does not yet answer the question

Comment: If that form is not an object of that workbook then the form unload would not be done, something has to trigger it. Can you please attach the screen from your VBA project tree (with both workbooks objects and form?